# How to display author name and post date in entity view page?

Tags: entities

I am using [Entity Construction Kit](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Structure
2. Select Content type
3. Click on the tap Display settings and unchecked Display author and date information

[image]